# Reading .tar files in Spark and loading to Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, php-ziparchive

I am trying to read .tar files that were located ona linux machine.

tar files had .gz files and text files with in that.

I want to write a spark program to pick the tar file and load the .gz files or underlying text files to Hive table.

the Spark APIs were very confusing. some are using binaryFiels, TextFiles and WholeTextFile API.

Can someone recommed a good example and API for my requirement.

Update: Spark Version: 2.0.2

Comment: Why the `spark-streaming` and `ziparchive` tags? And which version of Spark?

Comment: Spark 2.0.2. If possible i would like to push the file as stream to Hive. I am still fine with batch processing of the files.

Comment: Did you ever resolve reading in TAR into hive? Not a tar.gz but just a tar